# Add yellow line of pixels to image every 8 horizontal pixels

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, love2d

I have a very long image (824x8) of a bunch of characters from a font. I want to use the image as an [image font](https://love2d.org/wiki/ImageFontFormat) in Love2D.

Love2D can take an image of a font with yellow lines (or any other color of line, really) in-between each character and convert it to a pixel-perfect font Love2D can use.

[Here's an image that sorta shows what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W9DI.png)

Is it possible to add these yellow lines with ImageMagick?

Edit: I am using the Windows command line.

Comment: Since the answer to the question above is "Yes", please have a look at the ImageMagick Examples web pages. So more specifically do you want someone to write that for you? If so, using which language? ImageMagick can be used lots of ways.

Comment: If all the parts of the characters are completely connected but the characters do not touch each other, then you can use -connected-components processing to separate the characters, then append them back together with yellow bars in-between. Please supply your IM version and platform and the input image alone. I can try to show you how to do that in Unix Imagemagick command line form. I do not know any APIs, so you would have to translate that.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the info to my post. I need it to make 8x8 squares separated by yellow lines.

Comment: You did not say what version of Imagemagick. Is it IM 6 or IM 7. Syntax is different. IM 6 uses convert. IM 7 uses magick.

Comment: This info isn't useful anymore, but for future reference, I'm using IM7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to just insert yellow lines into your existing image between every 8 pixel section, you can try something like this with Imagemagick ...

```
convert input.png -background yellow ^
   -crop 8x0 -splice 1x0 +append +repage -crop 0x8 -splice 0x1 -append result.png
```

That crops the image into 8 pixel wide strips vertically, adds a stripe of yellow to the left edge of each strip, then reassembles them. Then it crops the image horizontally into 8 pixel high strips, adds a single yellow edge to each, and reassembles them.

That increases the final dimensions because it adds the yellow lines between rows of the input image rather than overlay a grid onto the input image.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, aside from the lines above the image! Thank you!

Edit: for future reference, here's one without the lines above: `convert "C:\path\to\file.png" -background yellow ^ -crop 8x0 -splice 1x0 +append +repage -crop 0x8 -append "C:\path\to\result.png"`

Answer (score 0):

For a simple 8x8 overlay grid, from a Windows command line you can do something like this...

```
convert input.png ( xc:none[7x7] -background yellow -splice 1x1 -roll +0+0 ) ^
   -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:u.w]x%[fx:u.h]" -virtual-pixel tile -distort SRT 0 ^
   -compose over -composite result.png
```

That starts by reading in the input image and creating an 8x8 transparent cell with a single row of yellow on top and left. Then it sets the 8x8 cell image with a viewport the same dimensions as the input image, and tiles that cell to fully fill the viewport. Composite that grid over the input image to create the output.

If you want the cells to be 8x8 plus the yellow line, change the initial size of the cell to "xc:none[8x8]".

To shift the grid from the upper left corner you can adjust the "-roll +0+0" to start at someplace other than +0+0.

To use this in a BAT script make the single percent signs "%" into doubles "%%".